# Show network traffic

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to view the network traffic (http requests, raw http etc.) similar to `chrome dev tools` (`network tab`) generated by an application (`nodejs` if it makes any difference) via `vscode`?

This functionality is already present, but it doesn't show the requests and responses of the application running.

[image]

Comment: fyi, nodejs doesn't currently handle logging network traffic that well - keep an eye on https://github.com/nodejs/diagnostics/issues/75

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The developer tools are connected to the running instance of Code and not the application you are executing. Currently it is not possible to view network traffic for the application you are launching from Code.

Comment: That's good enough. Thank you. I've searched the plugins marketplace, but nothing is available. I assume no plugin is available either. Moreover do you happen to know of any material that could help me gain some insight on how to connect to the running application?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs#_debugging-your-node-application

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start from `mbehr1.vsc-webshark` plugin and use WireShark tools for catching your app network i/o.

It would be great a more detailed post about configuring launching Rust app (server) in debug mode, wireshark with VSCode integrated UI, and maybe internal browser in a single launch.json action, but I can't point anything close to it.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using Microsoft Edge DevTools [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/visual-studio-code/microsoft-edge-devtools-extension/get-started) is a plugin that adds it to vsCode.

[Screenshot of vsCode with DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaKJZ.png)