# Run the vsCode chrome debug seeing the chrome network console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-code

It's a simple question but very helpfull if it's possible.

sorry for the title I didn't found an creative way to ask this kkkk

I love the chorme network console, its perfect to see what i'm really sending from backend, but the debugger isn't that nice (for my opinion)... soo i use the vsCode Chrome Debug extension for debug and would like also to see the network ...

this question could be summarizedin that 2 pictures ...

I want this:

[image]

with this:

[image]

Is possible?

thx!

Answer (score 1):

Before, wasn't possible to have vsCode chrome debug running together with chrome DevTools, as soon as you try to open the chrome console, the debugger was disconnected.

But, now days with the latest vsDebug and Chrome it is possible.
You can simply launch vsCode chrome debug and open the chrome DevTools.
You can even debug on both at the same time.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the hell brakes loose when you have your chrome dev tools open and vscode debug session running. It starts wildly jump btw breakpoints in vscode and chrome,  and the 'paused on chrome' and 'paused on vscode' is overlapped.

Comment: indeed it's not optimal as if we could simple have the network tab inside the vsCode, but so far, this answer meets the criteria, "running chrome dev tools together with vsCode debug". A side note, I noticed that if you remove all breakpoints from the chrome dev tools, it works smother for vsDebug.
maybe we need to address this issue to vsCode chrome extension as a feature request.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821043/show-network-traffic).
Yes, this would be a nice feature in vsCode.

If you don't mind using Microsoft Edge DevTools [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/visual-studio-code/microsoft-edge-devtools-extension/get-started) is a plugin that adds it to vsCode.

Otherwise here is a [link](https://github.com/nodejs/diagnostics/issues/75) to a nodejs support request to add this capability, there is a possible solution and npm package you can install